# How to extract audio features for each video frame using pyAudioAnalysis

Tags: python, feature-extraction, audio-recognition

I'm trying something like extracting audio features for each video frame. I know there are 30 video frames and 16000 audio frames per second in the video file. I'm using pyAudioAnalysis python lib to achieve the goal but no success.
Here is my code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioBasicIO
from pyAudioAnalysis import ShortTermFeatures,MidTermFeatures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os,shlex, subprocess
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# -acodec pcm_s16le  -vn -ar 16000
command_line = "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ac 1 -ar 16000  -vn test_mono.wav"
#command_line = "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn test_stereo.wav"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
print(args)
processResult = subprocess.call(args) # Success!
print(processResult)
[SamplingRate, signals] = audioBasicIO.read_audio_file("test_mono.wav")
print(SamplingRate)
```

**Output**

> ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'test.mp4', '-ac', '1', '-ar', '16000', '-vn', 'test_mono.wav']
> 1
>
> 16000

```
#mid_feature_extraction(signal, sampling_rate, mid_window, mid_step,short_window, short_step):
MidFeatures,ShortFeatures,MidFeatureLabels=MidTermFeatures.mid_feature_extraction(signals, SamplingRate, 0.043*SamplingRate, 
                                                                                  0.043*SamplingRate,0.00016*SamplingRate,
                                                                                  0.00016*SamplingRate)
print('Mid Features Extr Success')
MidFeatures_Dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=MidFeatures.transpose(), columns=MidFeatureLabels)
print(type(MidFeatures))
#print(MidFeatures)
print(type(ShortFeatures))
#print(ShortFeatures)
print(type(MidFeatureLabels))
#print(MidFeatureLabels)
MidFeatures_Dataframe.to_csv('Audio_MidFeatures.csv')
print('Mid Features File Success')
```

**Output**

> Mid Features Extr Success
>
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>
> <class 'list'>
>
> Mid Features File Success

As per my calculations I should get 338 rows of audio features, and after a long time of struggle I'm getting 326 with the above parameters but still don't know how. If anyone can help me how, window and steps are working here. I know the basic concepts of window and step as work in CNN but not getting in this context.

Comment: Could you also put output?  You have print commands, but knowing what the printed output was might improve my understanding here.

Comment: Sure, wait a minute

Comment: @EngrStudent Please take a look now

Comment: I think "process results" needs a newline in front of it.  I would also like to see the shape of the numpy arrays instead of the type.  How long is sample?  what is its dim?

Comment: Could you detail your calculations please ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your calculations, but looking at the doc in the code [here](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/blob/b34b42778f33be46f71091d3be0d195ee865f6bb/pyAudioAnalysis/ShortTermFeatures.py#L531), `short_window` and `short_step` should be **in samples** (probably as well as `mid_window` and `mid_step`).

However in your code:

```py
#mid_feature_extraction(
    signal, sampling_rate, 
    mid_window, mid_step,
    short_window, short_step
)
midFeat,shortFeat,midFeatLabels=MidTermFeatures.mid_feature_extraction(
    signals, SamplingRate, 
    0.043*SamplingRate, 0.043*SamplingRate,
    0.00016*SamplingRate, 0.00016*SamplingRate
)
```

it seems that `short_step=short_window=0.00016*16000=2.56` which is not in samples. So it will be cast to integer and will be equal to `2` instead of `2.56`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already calculated that to be 2.56

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure, are you aware that it will be cast to int, so `short_step` and `short_window` will be equal to 2 ?

Comment: Oh no, I'm not. Good point. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer to be more clear. Hope it helps, otherwise, you could post your calculations, it will be easier to understand your expected result.